# GroupBy, Filtering in knockout.js

Tags: c#, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

How can i groupby, and filter in a table using knockout.js. I also try to expand and collapse row and this the code that I am somewhat successfull).

This is my distinc function, note at the moment it seem to only work on one data element ( i would like it to have it in the future to be distinct on a property for an object.

```
ko.observableArray.fn.distinct = function (prop) {
    var target = this;
    target.index = {};
    target.index[prop] = ko.observable({});

    ko.computed(function () {
        //rebuild index
        var propIndex = {};

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(target(), function (item) {
            var key = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(item[prop]);
            if (key) {
                propIndex[key] = propIndex[key] || [];
                propIndex[key].push(item);
            }
        });

        target.index[prop](propIndex);
    });

    return target;
};
```

This is my current object function

```
course(_id, _courseCode, _courseTitle, _courseCampus) {
    var self = this;
    this.id = ko.observable(_id);
    this.courseCode = ko.observable(_courseCode);
    this.courseTitle = ko.observable(_courseTitle);
    this.coursecampus = ko.observable(_courseCampus);
}
```

There is my viewmodel

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.courses = ko.observableArray().distinct('courseCode');
    this.gpCourseCode = ko.observableArray();
    this.mutated = ko.observableArray();

    this.switchMutated = function (code) {
        if (self.mutated.indexOf(code) > -1) {
            self.mutated.push(code);
        }
        else {
            self.mutated.remove(code);
        }
    };

    this.switchText = function (code) {
        if (self.mutated.indexOf(code) > -1) {
            return "-"
        }
        else {
            return "+"
        }
    };

    self.gpCourseCode.push("MATH1030");
    self.gpCourseCode.push("MATH1006");
    self.gpCourseCode.push("MATH1046");
    self.courses.push(new course("1", "MATH1030", "Calculus", "city1"));
    self.courses.push(new course("2", "MATH1030", "Calculus", "city2"));
    self.courses.push(new course("3", "MATH1030", "Calculus", "city3"));
    self.courses.push(new course("4", "MATH1006", "Linear algebra", "city1"));
    self.courses.push(new course("5", "MATH1046", "Discrete Math", "city2"));
    self.courses.push(new course("6", "MATH1006", "Linear algebra", "city2"));
    self.courses.push(new course("7", "MATH1046", "Discrete Math", "city1"));

    this.searchCode = ko.observable("");
    self.filteredRecords = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.gpCourseCode(), function (rec) {
            return (
                (self.searchCode().length == 0 || rec.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.searchCode().toLowerCase()) >= 0)
            )
        });
    });
}
```

This is my html

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Course Code</th>
            <th>Course Title</th>
            <th>Course Campus</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><input data-bind="value: searchCode" placeholder="Course Code" /></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: filteredRecords">
        <tr class="table-dark">
            <td><span data-bind="text: $data"></span></td>
            <td><span></span></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-bind="click: $root.switchMutated($data), text: $root.switchText($data)"></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- ko foreach: $root.courses.index.courseCode()[$data] -->
        <tr data-bind="css: { mutated: $root.mutated.indexOf($data.courseCode()) > -1 }">
            <td><span data-bind="text: $data.id"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: $data.courseCode"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: $data.courseTitle"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: $data.coursecampus"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here are my two issues

1. When I filter the search, my mutable array becomes empty, therefore all the element become expanded.
2. I would love to convert my gpCourseCode to be a class similar to course, but I am not to sure how to do a distinct on a class and not just one element.

I have a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jseb04/3a0rhtLz/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I filter the search, my mutable array becomes empty, therefore all the element become expanded.

That's because you have an error in your click handler. It should take a function reference and not a function call. So `click: $root.switchMutated($data)` should become: `click: $root.switchMutated` (within a foreach, the click handler gets passed the current item as its first parameter automatically).

You will however now have to initialize the `mutated` array yourself (or maybe reverse the logic so you don't have to). Your click handler was doing this by accident, since supplying a function call to the click handler will cause that function to be executed.